# Handle different return types in switchMap operator

Tags: android, rx-java

I use `RxBinding` and I have a case where I make use of `RxTextView`'s `textChangeEvents()` I filter them and pass them to `switchMap()` where I execute a network request (using `Retrofit`) to an endpoint based on another value.

tl;dr :

```
switchMap(new Func1<TextViewTextChangeEvent, Observable<List<String>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<String>> call(TextViewTextChangeEvent textViewTextChangeEvent) {

                    switch (visibleTab) {
                        case TAGS:
                            return presenter.executeSearchPostsByTag(searchBarText, String.valueOf(0));
                        case PEOPLE:
                            return presenter.executeSearchPostsByPeople(searchBarText, String.valueOf(0));
                        case COMPANIES:
                            return presenter.executeSearchPostsByCompanies(searchBarText, String.valueOf(0));
                        case JOBS:
                            return presenter.executeSearchPostsByJobs(searchBarText, String.valueOf(0));
                        default:
                            return presenter.executeSearchPostsByTag(searchBarText, String.valueOf(0));
                    }

                }
            })
```

but I can't have as a return type : `Observable<List<String>>` since I receive a different object from each request.

How should I deal with such a case ?

Comment: What do you want the return type to be though? Are you passing the data on to another component?

Comment: @Kiskae no, I just subscribe to the data so I can consume them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to use an intermediary `Completable` transformation to throw away all elements and just wait for the `onComplete` call.

For each item, add `.toCompletable().<Void>toObservable()` to turn the output into `Observable<Void>` instead of `Observable<List<String>>`. This works since completable ensures no elements are emitted, ensuring type-safety.

Another option that might work is declaring the output as `Observable<?>`, but those wildcards can cause some weird issues with generics.

Note that if you're using RxJava 2, then the call to ignore elements and just return nothing is `.ignoreElements().<Void>toObservable()`

Comment: Cool, I wasn't aware of : `.toCompletable().<Void>toObservable()`. Let me try it and I'll let you know.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that no items are emitted so I can't consume the responses to the subscriber.

Comment: You will need to define some common way to consume the output then. A single subscriber can't handle multiple disjoint data types